# Compute $((p\!-\!1)/2)!\pmod{\!p},\ p = 257,\,$ by Wilson, etc

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

The task is to calculate:
                            $128! \pmod{257}$
I know that I'm supposed to use Wilson's theorem but I don't know how to apply it here.

[Reopen note: we already have answers (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338965/show-that-r2-%e2%89%a1-%e2%88%921r%e2%88%921-pmod-p-r-p-1-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)) showing how to use Wilson's theorem to deduce $\,128!^2\equiv -1\equiv 16^2\pmod{\!257}\,$ so what remains is proving whether $\,128!\equiv 16\,$ or $\,128!\equiv -16\pmod{\!257}\ $ -- Bill D.]

Comment: $(-1)^{128}(128!)^2=128!(257-128)(257-127)...(256)=256!=-1\pmod{257}$ gives you the remainder of the square of $128!$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy - ah I think I see the first step now. 1(mod 257) = -256(mod257). 2(mod 257) = -255(mod 257). and keep going all the way to 128 which is in the middle.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy:  so that means $128!\equiv\pm16\pmod{257}$, but is $128!\equiv +16$ or $-16$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner There is a button near the top that says 'Ask Question'. You can use it.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy a bit of a patronising tone. Also it's worth checking to see if his question has been answered elsewhere on the site, which might take some time searching.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I can afford it.

Comment: @Bill could you have another look, please. There is discussion about the dupe closure.

Comment: @J.W.T See [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p) for how to determine the sign generally. Iirc part of that is here too but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @m123 Could you please double check if the problem asks about $128!$ or $128!^2.\ $ The latter is *much* more common (and easier). Did you devise the problem? If not, what is its source?

Comment: Thanks, @BillDubuque

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm sure that the problem asks about 128!
This was on our exam at faculty couple of weeks ago, so I guess that our teaching assistant came up with this example

Comment: @m123 Ok, I reopened it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a particularly nice way to find the sign, as shown here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293728/the-square-root-of-wilsons-theorem-when-p-equiv-1-mod-4?noredirect=1&lq=1

It's not hard, however, to run a quick program and show that the answer is 16 and not -16.

Comment: @J.W.T Oops I see I inadvertantly linked to the $\,p=3\pmod{4}$ vs. $\,p=1\pmod{4}\,$ MO thread (in the prior comment). But they are all linked together anyhow. Just in case you missed it.

Comment: @m123 Does your context presume knowledge of class groups of quadratic fields or related advanced notions, or is it just elementary number theory?

Comment: @BillDubuque Just elementary number theory