# Find the remainder when the $2006! + \dfrac{4012!}{2006!}$ is divided by $4013$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

$$2006!+\frac{4012!}{2006!}=x \pmod{4013}$$

> Answer: $x=1553.$

Solution: $$2006!+4012!/2006!=x\pmod{4013}$$
$$(2006!)^2 -2006!x+4012!=0\pmod{4013} (*)$$
$$4\cdot (2006!)^2-4\cdot 2006!x+4\cdot 4012!=0$$
$$(2\cdot 2006!-x)^2-x^2+4\cdot 40121=0$$
$$(2\cdot 2006!-x)^2=x^2-4\cdot 4012! \pmod{4013}(1)$$
For $x=1553$ we have
$$x^2=1553^2=601\cdot 4013-4 \implies 1553^2=-4\pmod{4013}.$$
On the other hands,
Since $4013$ is prime number,by
Wilson's theorem we have $(4012!+1);$ $4013$
It follows that $$4012!=-1\pmod{4013} (2)$$
$$4\cdot 4012!=-4\pmod{4013}$$
From $(1),(2),(3)$ we get
$$(2\cdot 2006!-1553)^2=1553^2-4\cdot 4012!\pmod{4013}
=-4-(-4)=0\pmod{4013}$$
$$(2\cdot 2016!-1553)^2=0\pmod{4013}$$
$$2\cdot 2016!-1553=\pmod{4013}$$
The last equality is always true
because of $$2\cdot 2016!=2\cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot 2016)
1553$$
Thus,we proved that $(1)$ is true for
$x=1553$ or $(*)$ is true for $x=1553.$

Therefore $$2006!+ 4012!/2006!=1553\pmod{4013}*$$

I need a method to solve the example without using the answer, please with full proof.

Comment: I need a method to solve the example without using the answer, please with full proof.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  The title is just a "word salad" and the body of your post simply presents a calculation.  The only hint as to what you want is in the Comment above.  Please use the body of your post to explain the setup and goal of the problem you want help with, and give the context so Readers can respond efficiently.

Comment: (2006! +4012! / 2006!) Find the remainder when the number is 4013

Comment: The given solution can be shortened like : To find the value of $x$ in $$2006!+\frac{4012!}{2006!}=x \pmod{4013}$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
2006!+(-1*-2*\dots -2006) &=x \pmod{4013}\\
2*2006! &= x \pmod{4013}
\end{matrix}
$$

But proceeding further without a calculator seems difficult (1553 is prime)

Comment: Mr. This is not a solution I worked using the answer Do you understand I need to calculate the example without using the answer

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: As mentioned above, $2006! = \frac{4012!}{2006!}$ mod $4013$, so by Wilson's theorem $(2006!)^2 = -1$. By trial and error I found that $62^2+13^2 = 4013$. You can then multiply $62$ by the inverse of $13$ $($mod $4013)$ to get a square root of $-1$, thus you get both of them. The trouble is determining which square root of $-1$ $2006!$ turns out to be!

Comment: Step by step solution please

Comment: @AlS For more on computing $((p-1)/2)! \equiv \pm1 \pmod p\,$ for a prime $\,p\equiv 1\pmod{4}\,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494477/242) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293728).

Comment: 2 • 2006! = X (mod 4013) Please prove how we calculate this.